# Boyer Moore k-mismatches algorithm fails

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, string-comparison, boyer-moore

I've done a program for string comparison with one mismatch at a programming website. It gives me wrong answer. I've working on it extensively but, I couldn't find testcases where my code fails. Can somebody provide me test cases where my code fails. I've done the comparison using Boyer Moore Horspool k-mismatches algorithm as it's the fastest searching algorithm

The code is as such

```
int BMSearch_k(string text, string pattern, int tlen, int mlen,int pos)
{    
int i, j=0,ready[256],skip2[256][mlen-1],neq;

for(i=0; i<256; ++i) ready[i] = mlen;
for(int a=0; a<256;a++) {
    for(i = mlen;i>mlen-k;i--)
    skip2[i][a] = mlen;
}    

for(i = mlen-2;i>=1;i--)    {
    for(j=ready[pattern[i]]-1;j>=max(i,mlen-k);j--)
        skip2[j][pattern[i]] = j-i;
    ready[pattern[i]] = max(i,mlen-k);
}

j = mlen-1+pos;
//cout<<"\n--jafffa--\n"<<pos<<"+"<<mlen<<"="<<j<<endl;
while(j<tlen+k) {
    //cout<<"\t--"<<j<<endl;
    int h = j;
    i=mlen-1;
    int neq=0,shift = mlen-k;

    while(i>=0&&neq<=k)    {
        //cout<<"\t--"<<i<<endl;
        if(i>=mlen-k)
            shift = min(shift,skip2[i][text[h]]);
        if(text[h]!= pattern[i])
            neq++;
        i--;
        h--;
    }
    if(neq<=k)
        return j-1;
    j += shift;
}

return -1;
}
```

Comment: How are you getting a wrong answer but at the same time can't find the testcase where it breaks? The string that doesn't work on the website is the string that should cause the break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't initialising your arrays correctly,

```
int i, j=0,ready[256],skip2[256][mlen-1],neq;

for(i=0; i<256; ++i) ready[i] = mlen;
for(int a=0; a<256;a++) {
    for(i = mlen;i>mlen-k;i--)
    skip2[i][a] = mlen;
}
```

On the one hand, you declare `skip2` as a `256×(mlen-1)` array, on the other hand, you fill it as a `(mlen+1)×256` array.

In the next loop,

```
for(i = mlen-2;i>=1;i--)    {
    for(j=ready[pattern[i]]-1;j>=max(i,mlen-k);j--)
        skip2[j][pattern[i]] = j-i;
    ready[pattern[i]] = max(i,mlen-k);
}
```

you use `ready[pattern[i]]` before it has been set. I don't know if those mistakes are what's causing the failing testcase, but it's easily imaginable that they do.

Answer (score 1):

If Daniel's suggestions do not solve the problem, here are a couple more things that look odd:

```
    return j-1;  // I would expect "return j;" here
```

This seems odd as if you have k=0,mlen=1, then the highest value that j can take is tlen+k-1, and so the highest return value is tlen-2.  In other words matching a pattern 'a' against a string 'a' will not return a match at position 0.

Another oddity is the loop:

```
    for(i = mlen-2;i>=1;i--) // I would expect "for(i = mlen-2;i>=0;i--)" here
```

it seems odd that in the preprocessing you will never access the first character in your pattern (i.e. pattern[0] is not read).